# What is the easiest way to start a mongodb copy server?

Tags: mongodb

Our mongodb server is running on AWS EC2 - it is using up a lot of the cpus of this server - which is also our Apache server - How Can I easily migrate the mongodb to another EC2 dedicated server?

Comment: What is the database size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to migrate with minimal downtime, a straightforward approach would be to use MongoDB replication:

- [Convert your current standalone node to a replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) by restarting your current `mongod` with a `--replSet` name and then running `rs.initiate()`. **NOTE:** The `rs.initiate()` step is a once off command that only needs to be run on a primary when the replica set is first created.
- If all went well, you should now have a single node replica set with your former standalone node as the primary (check `rs.status()` and `rs.conf()` in the `mongo` shell).
- Create your new EC2 instance and start up a new `mongod` process as a member of the same replica set (i.e. including the same `--replSet` name in the configuration). To avoid any unexpected issues, the new node should be running the same version of MongoDB as your original standalone server.
- Connect to your primary via the `mongo` shell and add the new `mongod` process as a secondary node:

  ```
  rs.add("mynewec2:27017")
  ```
- You should now have a two node replica set with a primary node and secondary node (which may be in a "startup" or "recovering" phase while data is syncing).
- **NOTE**: For a production MongoDB replica set configuration you would normally want to have a third node to maintain a quorum. This can either be a secondary or an [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/), which is a voting-only node that does not hold any data and only participates in elections. For the purposes of your migration a third node is optional, but recommended in the event there are any problems with the secondary while the data is being synced. With a two node replica set, both nodes must be online in order to maintain a primary. A three node replica set allows for [fault tolerance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/#consider-fault-tolerance) of 1 node failure.
- Assuming there were no firewall or communication errors, the node you added as a secondary should begin to sync data over the network from your original (primary node). Note: there are [alternative ways](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) to sync a replica set member (for example starting from a file copy backup).
- You can follow the sync progress using [`db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.printSlaveReplicationInfo/#db.printSlaveReplicationInfo) on the primary.
- Once your secondary node has caught up with the current primary (or is within 10s of the oplog time of the primary) you can use `rs.stepDown(60)` to force the current primary to stepdown. This should cause your secondary (newly provisioned host) to become the primary.
- At this point the migration is complete: you can now shutdown your original `mongod` host, and restart the new `mongod` in standalone mode.

To minimise the impact to application writes during this period, you can either:

- change your application to use a replica set connection so writes will automatically change to the current primary
- coordinate changing your application connection string with the stepdown of the (former) standalone primary